# Apache flume with kafka source, kafka sink and memory channel - throwing UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION

Tags: apache-kafka, flume-ng

I am new to Apache flume https://flume.apache.org/. For one of the use-case, I need to move data from the Kafka topic on one cluster (bootstrap: bootstrap1, topic: topic1) to topic with different name in a different cluster (bootstrap: bootstrap2, topic: topic2). There are another use-cases in same project which fits best for flume and I need to use same flume pipeline for this use-case though there are other options to copy from Kafka to Kafka.

I tried below configs and the results are as mentioned in each options.

#1: telnet to kafka sink (bootstrap2, topic2) --> works perfect.
configs:

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = netcat
a1.sources.r1.bind = localhost
a1.sources.r1.port = 44444

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.topic = topic2
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = bootstrap2
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.flumeBatchSize = 100
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.acks = 1
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.linger.ms = 1

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

#2: kafka as source(bootstrap1, topic1) and logger as sink --> works perfect.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 10
a1.sources.r1.batchDurationMillis = 2000
a1.sources.r1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = bootstrap1
a1.sources.r1.kafka.topics = topic1
a1.sources.r1.kafka.consumer.group.id = flume-gis-consumer
a1.sources.r1.backoffSleepIncrement = 1000

# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = logger

# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

#3: kafka as source (bootstrap1, topic1) and kafka as sink(bootstrap2, topic2) --> gives error as mentioned below the config.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1

# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 10
a1.sources.r1.batchDurationMillis = 2000
a1.sources.r1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = bootstrap1
a1.sources.r1.kafka.topics = topic1
a1.sources.r1.kafka.consumer.group.id = flume-gis-consumer1
a1.sources.r1.backoffSleepIncrement = 1000


# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.topic = topic2
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.bootstrap.servers = bootstrap2
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.flumeBatchSize = 100
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.acks = 1
a1.sinks.k1.kafka.producer.linger.ms = 1


# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 100
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100


# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Error:

```
(kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1) [WARN - org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater.handleCompletedMetadataResponse(NetworkClient.java:968)] [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 85 : {topic1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

Continuously shows above error.

ERROR upon terminating flume-ng command

```
(SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:158)] Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Failed to publish events
    at org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.process(KafkaSink.java:268)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:145)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Could not send event
    at org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink.process(KafkaSink.java:234)
    ... 3 more
```

Seeking help from the stackoverflow community on:

1. What config is going wrong here. Kafka topics exists in respective clusters. (Option 1 and Option 2 works fine and I can see messages flowing from source to sink)
2. Why producer thread is trying to produce in source kafka topic?

Comment: You should really be using MirrorMaker2 for copying between Kafka clusters

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for reply however the same flume pipeline is also serving few other use cases, so we wanted to use the same pipeline.

Comment: Alright, just saying there's more appropriate tools for such use cases, which are known to work. Can you please show the describe output for both topics in their clusters? And I'm not sure I understand your second question since the stacktrace says "sinktask"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today. My case is even worse because I host two topics on a single Kafka cluster.

It is really misleading that the producer thread in Kafka sink is producing back to the Kafka source topic.

I fixed the issue by ***setting `allowTopicOverride` to `false` for Kafka sink***.

Quote from Kafka **sink** part in [Flume document](https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.9.0/FlumeUserGuide.html):

> allowTopicOverride: Default is `true`. When set, the sink will allow a message to be produced into a topic specified by the `topicHeader` property (if provided).

> topicHeader: When set in conjunction with allowTopicOverride will produce a message into the value of the header named using the value of this property. ***Care should be taken when using in conjunction with the Kafka Source topicHeader property to avoid creating a loopback***.

And in Kafka **source** part:

> setTopicHeader: Default is `true`. When set to true, ***stores the topic of the retrieved message into a header, defined by the topicHeader property***.

So by default, Apache Flume store the Kafka source topic in `topicHeader` for each event. Then, Kafka sink by default write to the topic specify in `topicHeader`.